# Command in parcel.js --open 'google chrome' does not work on Windows, only works on MacOS

Tags: parceljs

I use parcel.js to set up my project. This command --open 'google chrome' does not work on Windows, only works on MacOS. The error is: Windows cannot find 'google'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser value passed to `--open [browser]` is platform-dependent:

- Windows: `chrome`
- Linux: `google-chrome`
- MacOS: `google chrome`

Parcel [uses the `opn` package](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/blob/75310e15f6fa3c8a0ce6593ada1bcca00240ea54/packages/core/parcel-bundler/src/utils/openInBrowser.js) to start the browser. From the [`opn` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn):

> Type: `string | string[]`
>
> Specify the app to open the `target` with, or an array with the app
>   and app arguments.
>
> The app name is platform dependent. Don't hard code it in reusable
>   modules. For example, Chrome is `google chrome` on macOS,
>   `google-chrome` on Linux and `chrome` on Windows.
>
> You may also pass in the app's full path. For example on WSL, this can
>   be `/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`
>   for the Windows installation of Chrome.